Persistent connections for AWS SES API using .NET SDK
I'm using the .NET SDK for AWS SESv2, and send via the API.
The docs state

Consider using persistent HTTP connections—Rather than incurring the overhead of establishing a separate new HTTP connection for each API request, use persistent HTTP connections. That is, reuse the same HTTP connection for multiple API requests.

I've read both the general and .NET documentation, but haven't found instructions how to do that.
I wrote an adapter MySesClient which sends emails via the SDK. It's registered as a singleton, and creates a single instance of AmazonSimpleEmailServiceV2Client (which I assume encapsulates the framework's HttpClient) and reuses it for the lifetime of the application.
I assume there's more to it than that. How do I reuse connections and/or the underlying HttpClient?
